# How to transform one declaration into another with a tricky macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Consider this declaration:

`sc_fifo_in<matrix<data_type, WIDTH, HEIGHT> > in;`

What I want is some macro like function or combination of them which would replace the declaration above into:

`sc_fifo_in<data_type> in[WIDTH * HEIGHT];`

My observation is that the `<` and `>` symbols couldn't be replaced by macro, because the name of the macro identifier can not contain such character.

So is there any alternative workaround ?

How can this be achieved with C++03 ???

Comment: It would be pretty simple to write a program that would read the file and do the replace for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver of course parsing would be a simplest solution, but the point here is to do that without reading the file, parsing it, etc

Comment: Use `typedef` then.

Comment: @Raindrop7 how ?

Comment: I would just use my editor (Sublime) to globally replace this across files.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "replace"? To make a macro work you will  need to replace `sc_fifo_in<matrix<data_type, WIDTH, HEIGHT> > in;` with macro first.

Comment: @VTT yes I want to do that first

Comment: Then what is the problem? `#define FOO sc_fifo_in<data_type> in[WIDTH * HEIGHT];`

Comment: use a template type alias

Answer (score 0):

If you have vim available to you, you can save the following commands in a file.

```
1,$s/sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge
wa
q
```

Let's call the file temp.vim.

You can execute:

```
vim -S temp.vim <filename>
```

to update the file.

Explanation of the `s` command:

```
  1,$s/sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

  1,$s -> substitue in all the lines of the file

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

       ^  ----    The pattern to subtitute -------                         ^
                                                                             ^ -- substitution   --   ^

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

                 ^     ^ -> Ignore everthing up to and including the second < after sc_fifo_in.

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

                        ^       ^ -> Capture everything up to the next , (data_type)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge


                                     ^       ^ -> Capture everything up to the next , (WIDTH)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge


                                                  ^       ^ -> Capture everything up to the next > (HEIGHT)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge


                                                                   ^       ^ -> Capture everything up to ; (in)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

                                                                                        ^ The data type (the first capture)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

                                                                                            ^ The variable name (the fourth capture)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

                                                                                               ^ WIDTH (the second capture)

       sc_fifo_in<[^<]*<\([^,]*\),\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^>]*\)>\s*>\s\([^;]*\);/sc_fifo_in<\1> \4[\2 * \3];/ge

                                                                                                    ^ HEIGHT (the third capture)
```